# How to perform a Windows Azure Backup?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm starting using Windows Azure to manipulate my azure databases. I don't have experienced in IT world, I'm just looking a way to backup my database (preferibly in a local computer) and restore it.

I started reading from here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj650016.aspx#copy

And I ran this code:

```
CREATE DATABASE destination_database_name 
AS COPY OF [source_server_name].source_database_name
```

But I'm not sure if it's working, in the next image, `contoso2` is my original database and the another is the copy, and this one does not have any table from the original source.

[image]

So, please guide about how to backup my datases not using commercial products.
If you need additional data, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading [Business Continuity in Windows Azure SQL Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh852669.aspx) which explains the underlying infrastructure available to you and the two main mechanisms for backup - ocpy database and export/import

Answer (score 1):

You have third party products available; some of which don't require you to purchase anything. [Here is a good summary](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidmcg/archive/2011/09/29/data-backup-strategies-for-windows-and-sql-azure.aspx) which is still valid. You can also use the Export/Import feature available right off the management portal of Windows Azure.

Comment: When I see the Export/Import feature the first time, I was confusing. I though that feature Export your database to another blob container

Comment: Yes - that what the export feature does; it exports your SQL data and object definition (tables, views, procs...) into a blob. You need to select the storage account and the container in which the blob will be saved.

Answer (score 1):

Well it is easy if you are using Sql Server 2012. If you are not then you can install the express version.

1. Select the database you want to back up in new portal of windows azure https://manage.windowsazure.com
2. In the footer you will have an option to import/export. Click export. This opens a modal popup. Select the storage account you want to use and type in a appropriate name to save the *.bacpac file.
3. Once the file is saved to storage, download it to local, open sql server 2012 management studio. Select the database server. Right click on it and in the context menu you will find Import Data-Tier Application. Select the bacpac file from you local and follow the settings.

At the end you will have your data residing on your local machine.